# What is wwwroot in asp.net vnext

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I create new asp.net mvc project in visual studio 2015.The project has a wwwroot file.What is this? 
[image]

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Quoting the official website:

> The **wwwroot** folder is new in ASP.NET 5.0. All of the static files in
> your project go into this folder. These are assets that the app will
> serve directly to clients, including HTML files, CSS files, image
> files, and JavaScript files. The wwwroot folder is the root of your
> web site. That is, http://some.hostname/ points to wwwroot, all URLs for
> static content are relative to the wwwroot folder.
>
> Code files should be placed outside of wwwroot. That includes all of your C# files and Razor files. > Having a wwwroot folder keeps a clean separation between code files and static files.

[Source](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/grunt-and-bower-in-visual-studio-2015#static-files)

It's worth mentioning that the term `wwwroot` itself is certainly not new and it's actually a convention used across many platforms (including J2EE applications and IIS itself with its `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` directory).

Similar conventions in the Unix/Linux world are `htdocs`, `public_html` and `www`.

Comment: Another interesting note is that the name wwwroot is not actually special. Your project.json defines what this folder is called. If you change it then wwwroot becomes a normal folder in VS and the new folder gets the special icon. Originally it was called public, and that may even still be the default, but wwwroot is scaffolded due to its familiarity.

Comment: For best pratices where should TypeScript files should be placed ? For example I have an application which is separated by module (e.g. /account, /users, /calendar) where each modules have both `TypeScript` files and `html templates`. How should this case be handled in your opinion ?

Comment: If those `.ts` files need to available to the client (typically for client-side compilation), then definitely under `wwwroot` (perhaps `wwwroot/scripts`). If they're pre-compiled, they shouldn't be under `wwwroot`.

Comment: Been a while since this was answered and the 'Source' link looks a like it leads somewhere else now so I thought I'd add link discussing wwwroot for asp.net-core v2.1: [asp.net-core static files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Answer (score 30):

The `wwwroot` folder is new in **ASP.NET 5** to store **all of the static files in your project. Any files including HTML files, CSS files, image files, and JavaScript files which are sent to the user's browser should be stored inside this folder**.

Code files should be placed outside of `wwwroot`, including C# files and Razor views. Having a `wwwroot` folder keeps a clean separation between code files and static files. It brings clarity to the items that will be sent to the server and the items that should remain on the dev machine. If you look at the screenshot, `wwwroot` folder has css and lib sub folders. Css folder is a place to keep your custom css files, while lib folder is used by Bower package manager. The lib folder contains the packages downloaded by Bower and can contain css, js and images.

The screenshot shows that lib folder has a bootstrap package folder. If you expand it, you will find css, js, as well all other assets related to the bootstrap package.

In **MVC4**, we used the content folder to keep style sheets as well as scripts folder for referenced scripts. These folders are gone now, so it's important to understand that there is no single folder for style sheets or scripts. They could be in any of the folders within `wwwroot`.

It's interesting to note that if you wish to reference the css, js, or img files in your razor views, using the ~ keyword ensures direct path to the `wwwroot` folder. So suppose you wanted to reference site.css in your view, you can access it using the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />` syntax.

You can see that the `~` keyword points to the `wwwroot` folder.

[image]