# ASP.NET MVC 6 (vNext) not properly linking to files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to run the ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 sample ["HelloMVC"](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/tree/dev/samples/1.0.0-beta4/HelloMvc) project, with a custom CSS file.

I place my .css files in the `wwwroot` folder, let's say in a `styles` folder.

I then link to it in my `_Layout.cshtml` with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/styles/mystyle.css" />
```

However, the style doesn't get rendered.

If I go to the URL of the expected file in my browser (let's say I'm running on port 12345, so I go to `http://localhost:12345/styles/mystyle.css`, I'm greeted with a cheeky page (pure HTML) with a lightbulb and a smiley face that says "`Your ASP.NET 5 application has been successfully started`".

In fact, if I go to *any* URL for the running app, I'm greeted with the same page. i.e. going to `http://localhost:12345/thisfiledoesntexist.jpg` will return the same page.

Is this ASP.NET 5's current `404` page? Why aren't my styles getting rendered? I would think this would be a very simple thing.

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648045/what-is-wwwroot-in-asp-net-vnext) it seems that what I'm doing would be the proper way. In fact, Visual Studio even has intellisense for the css files that I've added when typing out the href.

Comment: I think the issue is with `App.UseWelcomePage()`. See https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/113

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing `app.UseWelcomePage();` from `Startup.cs` fixed this, as per [Sami Kuhmonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1806780/sami-kuhmonen)'s suggestion (and helpful link to https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/113)