# How can I set the default debug folder in VS2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I am developing an asp.net web app in VS2015. I see that I can debug it using IIS Express or web. The problem is that they point to different folders so the paths of a file has to be modify accordingly. In particular IIS Express points to wwwroot, instead web points to src. How can I edit the folders they point to?

Comment: Why should you have to edit anything?  What do you mean `web`? You mean IIS? Also `wwwroot` only exists in ASP.NET 5 projects. `wwwroot` is *not* a debug folder, it's the location of static files. All code and dynamic files are stored outside it. Are you confused about what the ASP.NET 5 differences perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is wwwroot in asp.net vnext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648045/what-is-wwwroot-in-asp-net-vnext)

Answer (score 0):

On the solution explorer focus on project item and then select the project properties on pop up menu.

In the "web" tab (see left side of the opened window int he client area of the ide), you can select the folder of your projects and if use IIS Express or IIS running on your OS(or another instance in the intranet).

Comment: `wwwroot` exists only in ASP.NET 5 projects and has special meaning. Changing the virtual directory won't change that. The OP  is probably confused about the different folder structure of ASP.NET 5

Comment: oh well, I didn't know... in fact it seemed me strange that IIS Express were pointing to wwwroot.. but all it is possible :)

Comment: I don't see any web tabs

Comment: Search for the the tab that allows you to change from IIS Express in VStudio or a web server, in the first case you can also choice a folder and a starting file to run your debug session.. however I think that Kanavos has centered the problem, and you have created some ASP.NET 5 projects that is "a bit" different from ASP.NET 4.6 and previous version.. so refer to his comments questions and answers.. I thought it were set up bad some configurations..