# ASP.Net website and multi-target frameworks - dependency error

Tags: c#, asp.net, multitargeting

I've got an ASP.Net website (that's really old). One of the projects (let's call it **OurCore**) that we have in the solution, has been updated to support both .NET Framework 4.6.1, and .NET Standard 2.0.

When I build the solution in Visual Studio, I get this warning: **"Could not get dependencies for project reference 'OurCore'".** However, I am able to build both Debug and release locally in Visual Studio.

When I attempt to build the solution using a TFS automated build, it fails with this different error: 
**C:\agent_work\19\s\OurCommon\OurCore\OurCore.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "GetTargetPath" does not exist in the project.**

This StackOverflow issue linked below is basically the same thing I am getting, but it has not been resolved. Does anyone have any ideas?

[Problem with multi target frameworks in asp web site project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373711/problem-with-multi-target-frameworks-in-asp-web-site-project/61280473#61280473)

Comment: What does your project file look like?

Comment: Because it's an old ASP.Net website app, there's not a project file for it. Building it does create a metaproj file, but that's done on the fly.

One option that I am trying is to convert this to a web application project, to see if that will allow me to resolve it.